# Keep variable persistent between calls in background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to do the following in my extensions background page:

```
<script>
var tabStatus = [];
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  [...]
  if(something){
    tabStatus.push(tabId)
  }else{
    tabStatus.splice(tabStatus.indexOf(tabId), 1);
  }
  [...]
});
</script>
```

I want to keep the tabStatus array between script runs, but every time the script gets called it is empty again. Is there a way to make this work?

Just to clarify: I don't need the data to be stored between browser restarts. Just in one session I want to have the same tabStatus array everytime the listener function gets called.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean persistent between browser restarts, then you need to use [`localStorage`](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/).

Comment: No, I just mean between two runs of the Listener. So that every time I change the url, and the listener gets called I have the same tabStatus. It doesn't need to be stored between browser restarts.

Comment: @Kai `tabs.onUpdated` listener is called twice per tab update, is your code aware of it? If yes then you must be cleaning `tabStatus` somewhere. If you show full method maybe I can see something.